# PostgreSQL: The anonymous DO block's void retun type

Tags: postgresql, internals, postgresql-11

PostgreSQL has anonymous DO blocks explained in detail here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html.

This clearly indicates that
The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, **returning void**. It is parsed and executed a single time.

I was wondering if there is a way to execute the **DO block** with no parameters but returning a type dynamically?

The following example will explain my requirement. I want to indicate that my use of ***plpgsql*** is just an example! It could be any `LANGUAGE` in PostgreSQL environment

```
DO $$
BEGIN
    Return SELECT table_schema, table_name FROM information_schema.tables
             WHERE table_type = 'VIEW' AND table_schema = 'public'
END$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

ERROR: RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning void
```

Before anybody runs over to the answer section and explains that I am asking for a contradiction, I want to continue my story with the following. PostgreSQL provides a `CREATE LANGUAGE` feature https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createlanguage.html.
If we look at the `inline` parameter, it will say:

> INLINE inline_handler
>
> inline_handler is the name of a previously registered function that
>   will be called to execute an anonymous code block (DO command) in this
>   language. If no inline_handler function is specified, the language
>   does not support anonymous code blocks. The handler function must take
>   one argument of type internal, which will be the DO command's internal
>   representation, and it will **typically return void.** The return value of
>   the handler is ignored.
>
> Typically return void

Does **typically return void** imply that there is a scenario where one can use the `DO` block to return something other than void?

If there is a method to achieve anonymous code execution but without a DO block, and with custom return type, I would be interested.

Please note the question's *internals* tag: this is a question about how things work.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return results from `DO`.

The closest equivalent would be to create a function in the `pg_temp` schema, which then is a *temporary function* and is automatically dropped when the database session ends.